# Angular material mat-select styling issues

Tags: angular, sass, styles

I am using angular 8.0.0, angular material and [Fuse Theme as admin panel](http://angular-material.fusetheme.com/apps/dashboards/analytics).
The issue is that whenever i change the style of mat-select it gets applied but after one or two refresh the angular material overrides the local component changes  and applies the default.
Also it gets applied to all components how can i change style of only one single mat-select?

part of my html where the problem is :

```
   <form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label class="label-colors"> bla bla </mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="">
            <mat-option value="active" class="empty-select">bla bla</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="inactive" >bla bla</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
       <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label class="label-colors"></mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="isReserved">
            <mat-option value="active"></mat-option>
            <mat-option value="inactive"></mat-option>
        </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```

scss file :

```
.mat-select-arrow{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)!important;
  }
  .label-colors {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  
  // mat-input caret color
  .input-element-color {
    caret-color: #ffffff !important;
  }
  .blue{
    background-color: blue; 
}
.mat-form-field-underline{
  background-color: rgb(61, 82, 89)!important;
}
.date-icons{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
   th{
    font-weight: bold !important ;
    color:black !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
  // .mat-select-value-text{
  //   color: #fff!important;
  // }

  .mat-form-field{
    //width: 155px; 
    margin: 3px;
  }
  // body.theme-default .mat-select-value{
  //   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
  // }
  .editdeleteicon{
    color: #003042;
  }
  .fix-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   max-width: 88px; 
   padding: 0 10px !important;
  }
  .fix-text :hover{
    overflow: visible;
```

}

tried every suggestion on stackoverflow but cant seem to be able to change the color of mat-select and keep it that way even if i can, when i change it does change everywhere else. I hope I am clear

**UPDATE:** Fixed by adding class mat-form-field and then in scss

```
 .example-class{
    // inside this class added:
    .mat-select-value-text {
        color: red;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you used !important which is helpful sometimes for overwriting css, but in this case you have some thing more to do because it is part of the angular material module.
So, you have 2 options:

1- add ::ng-deep before the class. for example

`::ng-deep .className {
 color: blue !important
}`

2- Or you should write the same thing you wrote up there but in the style.css (or style.scss depending on if you are using css or scc) but that would imply that those changes will apply to the component everywhere in your app, so for example if you're using mat-select in another part of your app your changes here will affect it because the scope of the style.css/style.scss is on all the app.

So you can choose the method you need.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I though ng-deep is deprecated also it says in angular.io but i will try.